# iTunes Utility - Merging Libraries

Tags: macos, itunes

I would like to merge three separate iTunes libraries.  Here is more information:

- Currently have 3 separate iTunes libraries on 2 laptops and and dekstop.
- Want to merge all three onto the desktop (i.e. it has all content), while maintaining the other two laptop based libraries as-is.
- I want to avoid getting a slew of duplicates within the merged library.
- I am not concerned about maintaining the library (i.e. playlists, etc.) on desktop.
- I am not concerned with maintaining perfect sync, so could repeat the necessary procedure periodically to remerge libraries.

I am ok with using the command line, Python or applescript if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sync libraries one-way with rsync:

```bsh
rsync -av --force --delete --size-only ~/Music/iTunes /Volumes/johndoe/Music
```

A detailed writeup is here: [Keeping 2 iTunes Libraries in Sync](https://web.archive.org/web/20170111194835/http://guides.macrumors.com/Keeping_2_iTunes_Libraries_in_Sync)

I actually use this technique myself.

Creates a "carbon copy" of a library on another machine which you can then sync to reflect changes.

Works best with two Macs, never tried it with a PC.

Comment: Ok - thanks.  I'll give it a try, but if there are any script type recipes out there that's be great too.

Comment: Updated question with script method!

Comment: where were you when I asked my question about syncing itunes libraries (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/how-can-i-sync-my-itunes-music-library-between-two-computers-for-free)?  that link is great :P